# Redirect a folder to a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am trying de redirect these types of URLs :

```
https://www.example.com/my-account/VARIABLE-FOLDER/
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/my-account/VARIABLE-FOLDER/home/
```

I am not really familiar with complex redirects with htaccess, can someone help me ?

I tried this but without results :

```
RewriteRule ^my-account/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/my-account/(.*)$/home/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

There are all my htaccess rules at the moment :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Thanks by advance

---

UPDATE #1, i just tried this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(mon-compte/.*)/?$ https://vide.ecoles-libres.fr/$1/home/ [R=301,NC,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And i am now redirected like that :
https://example.com/my-account/VARIABLE-FOLDER/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home//home/

Comment: Could you please do let us know if you have any more htaccess Rules apart from shown one?

Comment: I just did it :)

Comment: Sure, thanks for adding it, I added an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your shown attempts, please try following. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
##Add an additional condition to check about URI here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/home [NC]
RewriteRule ^(my-account/.*)/?$ https://www.example.com/$1/home/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I just tried it, unfortunately it does not seems to work, I cleared the cache and even tried with a different browser with private navigation.

Comment: @JonathanCollery, please do let me know what is the url you are hitting? what error are you getting?

Comment: I still hit : https://www.example.com/my-account/VARIABLE-FOLDER/ and not : https://www.example.com/my-account/VARIABLE-FOLDER/home/

And I don't get any errors.

Comment: Precision : I have this piece of code also in my htaccess (in top of it) :

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF-Visitor} '"scheme":"http"'
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: @JonathanCollery, ok, please try my updated rules once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Ok, an upgrade ! I am now redirect but to an url like that :
https://example.com/my-account/VARIABLE-FOLDER/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home/home//home/

I also UPDATED with #1 my htacess at the moment, because I had to take the request out of the main "block" because I feel like WordPress (the CMS I use) automatically deletes this the request you proposed to me every time ...

Comment: @JonathanCollery, ok, I have updated my answer now, could you please do check updated rules now and let me know then.

Comment: It works perfectly ! I just hope that WordPress will not delete again your request.
In all cases, huge thanks man for yor disponibility :) !

Comment: @JonathanCollery, your welcome, cheers happy to help here.